# Showing version info in UI in a windows app

Tags: .net, winforms

In my .net windows application, am seting major,minor,build and revision numbers in AssemblyInfo.cs file.

To display this in the UI, which one of the following method should I be using..shud i be using #1 as it does not use reflection?
Whats the difference between the 2?

```
Application.ProductVersion
```

or

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio if you add a new `AboutBox` to your project you'll you'll notice that the second technique is used to obtain the version that will be displayed in the about box.

However, the first technique is useful if you define the `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute` in your executable since `Application.ProductVersion` first checks if this attribute is defined before defaulting to obtaining the version from other places.

The `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute` is most useful when you want to specify a version in a non-conventional format, like for example: *A1.2*